# Android: If user doesn't complete Registration he still can get to MainActivity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

my app start with register activity that asks for their phone num, after entering phone numb a otp code would be received then entered to access the final stage of creating an account which is setup profile name and picture.

my problem is if the user closed the app when he is setup profile activity which is after otp,
next time he opens the app he would still be logged in even if the phone and account is not created yet at firebase.

SetProfileActivity:

```
public class SetupProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySetupProfileBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    Uri selectedImage;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySetupProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading Profile Setting...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);


        binding.profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 45);
            }
        });

        binding.finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    binding.nameBox.setError(getString(R.string.cant_be_empty));
                    return;
                }
                dialog.show();

                if (selectedImage !=null){
                    StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Profiles").child(auth.getUid());
                    reference.putFile(selectedImage).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        String imageUrl = uri.toString();

                                        String uid = auth.getUid();
                                        String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                                        String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString().trim();

                                        User user = new User(uid, name, phone, imageUrl);

                                        database.getReference()
                                                .child("Users")
                                                .child(phone)
                                                .setValue(user)
                                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    String uid = auth.getUid();
                    String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                    User user = new User(uid, name, phone, "No Image");
                    database.getReference()
                            .child("Users")
                            .child(phone)
                            .setValue(user)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data !=null){
            if (data.getData() !=null){
                binding.profileImageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
                selectedImage = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }

    // check if want to exit
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.click_again_to_Exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged with `firebase-realtime-database` I'm going to assume that is where you store the additional profile information.

If so, you will have to:

1. Try and read the profile information for the current user when the app starts.
2. If the information exists, redirect them to the main activity.
3. If the information does not exist, redirect them to the registration page.

Comment: Kind words, but are you aware of the concept of accepting answers and upvoting answers?

Comment: thanks alot for answer: i got another problem with firebase auth

Comment: iam using my real phone to create an account and got my otp to make sure the app is working, after finish testing i removed my real phone num and account assosiated with it from the realtime firebase, but when i tried to create a new account with the same num even after removing it i don't receive OTP

Comment: It's hard to say why that is EIY, but make sure that you also deleted the user account from Firebase Authentication. In general, the Firebase documentation recommends using fictional numbers to test: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers